# Values not displaying in Angular select box while binding Ngmodel

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I am a beginner in Angular and when I tried to display object by looping in select box, it not displaying any values. Only showing blank dropdown.

My html page like the following:

```
<div *ngIf="userPermissionObj">
 <select id="permission">
   <option *ngFor="let obj of permissionType"
    [value]='permissionType.value' 
    [selected]="userPermissionObj.sPermissionType == obj.value ? true : null">
    {{permissionType.viewValue}}
   </option>
 </select>  
</div>
```

My component ts file contains like the following code,

```
getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch()
{
  var param:string=this.permissionRequestUser;
    this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
      .subscribe((data:any)=> {this.userPermissionObj=data;});
}

permissionType = [
{value: 'R', viewValue: 'Read'},
{value: 'W', viewValue: 'Write'}
];
```

Where have I wrongly implemented my html page?

Comment: `.sPermissionType ` is it a typo or regular property name ?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `[value]='permissionType.value'` by `[value]='obj.value'` and `{{permissionType.viewValue}}` by `{{obj.viewValue}}` because permissionType is the array you are looping with.
So you're HTML should look like this

```
<div *ngIf="userPermissionObj">
  <select id="permission">
   <option *ngFor="let obj of permissionType"
     [value]='obj.value' 
     [selected]="userPermissionObj.sPermissionType == obj.value ? true : null">
     {{obj.viewValue}}
  </option>
 </select>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{permissionType.viewValue}}`, use`{{obj.viewValue}}`.

The iteration `*ngFor="let obj of permissionType"` where you chose `obj` as a variable. So you will have to use the same variable for the value interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

For a correct data binding you have to add an ngModel to the select and remove the selected attribute of the option.

```html
<div *ngIf="userPermissionObj">
 <select id="permission" [(ngModel)]="userPermissionObj.permissionType">
   <option *ngFor="let permission of permissionType"
    [value]="permission.value">
       {{permission.viewValue}}
   </option>
 </select>  
</div>
```

in you ts

```js
getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch(): void
{
  const param:string=this.permissionRequestUser;
   this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
      .subscribe((data:any)=> {
           this.userPermissionObj = data;
   });
}

permissionType = [
{value: 'R', viewValue: 'Read'},
{value: 'W', viewValue: 'Write'}
];
```